# How to take a "peek" to see whether a read coroutine would complete instantaneously?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write an async bridge between two instant messengers, let's say IRC and Telegram. Here's my code so far that doesn't work:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import random

async def read_from_irc(sock):
    n = random.randint(1, 5)
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    return "read_from_irc" + str(n)

async def read_from_telegram(sock):
    n = random.randint(1, 5)
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    return "read_from_telegram" + str(n)

async def main():

    sock1 = await connect_to_irc()
    sock2 = await connect_to_telegram()

    while True:
        w1 = read_from_irc(sock1)
        w2 = read_from_telegram(sock2)
        waits = {w1, w2}
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(waits)
        print(done)
        print(pending)
        if w1 in done:
            msg = await w1
            await write_to_telegram(msg)
        if w2 in done:
            await write_to_irc(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
    asyncio.run(main())
```

My problem is that in reality, read_from_irc() and read_from_telegram() are running read() functions that can block if there's no data waiting. Sometimes I want to send a message from IRC to Telegram, sometimes the other way round so I think I need to know when it's a good moment to read from IRC and when there's some data pending on Telegram. How to determine that in this example? This is the error I'm trying to avoid:

```
RuntimeError: readuntil() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
```

Comment: Isn't that an equivalent to the halting problem?

Comment: `f1` and `f2`? Can you sync up your text with your code?

Comment: @DeepSpace you're right - I clarified by noting that I want to see if there's anything I can read from a socket